# Does Migration Assistant migrate macports?

Tags: macports, migration, migration-assistant

New MacBook Pro here.  I am about to use Migration Assistant to copy over my old files from my old first-gen MacBook.  Will I have to reinstall macports manually or will Migration Assistant copy my /opt directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The copying should work without a problem, but if you happen to upgrade to Snow Leopard at the same time, you might run into some compatibility issues, depending on the "ports" you have installed. Same goes for old "ports" that may have been specifically built for your old system (maybe processor dependent), you could run into problems there, too.

Remember to run `selfupdate`, and `upgrade` the installed ports (where needed).

Comment: I have a question on note, on the latest MacBookPro '18 there is a MacPorts user created with the migration and without connecting to that user first is impossible to log to the migrated user without using the recovery key, how to get rid of this mechanism ?

Comment: @AKFourSeven: Unfortunately, I do not fully understand your question, especially regarding the recovery keys - may I suggest you open a new question with your request instead? Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: I did made a question out of it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331107/new-macbook-pro-migration-assitant-login-issues) but no one seems to get it (I even got negged for it)

Comment: @Asmus See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/how-to-delete-macports-user-after-using-the-migration-assistant for that. And I can confirm it works for Catalina.

Comment: @AKFourSeven See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/how-to-delete-macports-user-after-using-the-migration-assistant for that also. I can confirm it works for Catalina.