# How to delete MacPorts user after using the Migration Assistant

Tags: macos, user-account, macports, migration

My 2012 MacBook Air (11", i7 2GHz 8GB RAM) crashed and I had to erase the SSD and re-install macOS High Sierra with the Internet Recovery Mode tools. Once I had the working OS, I used the Migration Assistant to rebuild my system from a Time Machine backup. Upon restoring my system, I ended up with MacPorts as a User. I am at a loss to understand why this happened and am wondering if I should get rid of it?

```
$  port installed
Error: Current platform "darwin 17" does not match expected platform "darwin 16"
Error: If you upgraded your OS, please follow the migration instructions: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration
OS platform mismatch
    while executing
"mportinit ui_options global_options global_variations"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, OS platform mismatch
```

I had originally started this computer with macOS Mountain Lion. I'd installed MacPorts when using macOS Sierra. Prior to the crash I had macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 (and that is what I have now).

As I recall, I've only used MacPorts ever to install one thing - I think it was Valgrind (which is not functional in High Sierra - so I don't need it). Of note - there is *not* a "MacPorts" User that I can login with or see in the Sys Prefs >>> Users & Groups:

[image]

...but there **is** a "macports" directory in `/Users/`:

[image]

Any ideas on why Migration Assistant would create a MacPorts user? Thought on how to and whether or not to nuke it (and any other MacPorts components?)

---

**Update:**

I removed MacPorts per their instructions: https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html

...and I removed /opt/local/bin from my $PATH, then deleted /Users/MacPorts.

Upon rebooting, MacPorts is still a User that shows up in the login screen. Also I get the following from `dscl`:

```
$  dscl . list /Users | grep -v '^_'
daemon
Guest
macports
mixelpix
nobody
root
```

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Darwin 16 is Sierra

Comment: @klanomath yep. I'd installed MacPorts when I had Sierra. Had upgraded to High Sierra, then the Macbook Air crashed. Thanks!

Comment: The answer also works for Catalina incidentally. I just had the same problem after an upgrade to MacBook Pro 16" (tired of the butterfly keyboard problems). Thanks a lot for asking the question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
$  dscl . list /Users | grep -v '^_'
daemon
Guest
macports <--------------------------------------------- remove?
mixelpix
nobody
root

$  /usr/bin/dscl . -search /Users name macports
macports        dsAttrTypeNative:name = (
    macports <----------------------------------------- confirm...
)

$  sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "/Users/macports" <---- DELETE
Password:

$  dscl . list /Users | grep -v '^_' <----------------- GONE!
daemon
Guest
mixelpix
nobody
root
```

Also useful: `sudo ls /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users`

Similarly, to delete the group "macports" use:

```
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "/Groups/macports"
```

Comment: This solution does not quite solve the OP's question about the account being a new login option after migration. While this is effective at removing the `macports` user from a possible account to log in as, it also breaks MacPorts which does need & use the user and group called `macports`. Fixing this seems to require reinstalling MacPorts. [This post](https://www.mail-archive.com/macports-users@lists.macports.org/msg07359.html) from the macports-users list offers some clarity.

Comment: @roens The OP wanted to remove the macports user after deinstalling MacPorts.

Comment: @nohillside My mistake… and now my earlier comment is too old to edit. Tho the other part of my earlier comment may help someone like myself, wanting to keep using MacPorts after Migration.

Comment: @roens you can always post an answer yourself. Just make sure it adresses the question asked as well and  stands on its own (so start with how to remove the user, not with „in addition to the other answer“).