# SIP preventing deletion of /opt/local

Tags: mojave, macports, sip

Ran into the same problem tonight as [this question from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797208/root-user-cant-delete-file) that wasn't fully answered.

I'm trying to uninstall an old installation of MacPorts, and run into SIP:

```
mybox:~ me$ sudo rm -rf /opt/local
rm: /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences: Operation not permitted
rm: /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library: Operation not permitted
rm: /opt/local/var/macports/home: Operation not permitted
rm: /opt/local/var/macports: Directory not empty
rm: /opt/local/var: Directory not empty
rm: /opt/local: Directory not empty
```

According to the original question, the answer seems to involve SIP… but why has SIP decided to protect this (empty) directory?

EDIT: Here's the results of `ls -a` in the directory:

```
./ ../
```

And here's the results of `ls -leOd /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences`:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  wheel  - 64 Nov  8 19:45 /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences/
```

.

EDIT 2018-11-12:

Here's the results of `ls -laeO@ /opt/local/var/macports/home`

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  - 96 Nov  8 19:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  - 96 Nov  8 19:45 ../
    com.apple.FinderInfo    32 
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  - 96 Nov  8 19:42 Library/
```

EDIT 2018-11-13:

Here's the results of `xattr -l /opt/local/var/macports`

```
com.apple.FinderInfo:
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........@.......|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020
```

Comment: are you sure it is empty or does it has hidden files

Comment: There are a number of possible causes for this error. Check the directories' access control list (ACL) and flags with e.g. `ls -leOd /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences`. If that lists a "restricted" flag, the directory of protected by SIP. There are a number of other flags that might forbid deletion; see `man chflags` for a partial list of them. I don't think an ACL could have this effect, but it doesn't hurt to check that as well. You can add the results to your question by editing it (note: please use code format, as you did for the original errors).

Comment: @Buscar웃 I checked. `ls -a` returns `./ ../`

Comment: command+Shift+`.` will show hidden files

Comment: @GordonDavisson I added the results to the question.

Comment: @Buscar웃 From Finder? That didn't show anything, either.

Comment: "Why has SIP decided to protect this (empty) directory?" Because SIP is weird. Turn it off, delete the directory, then turn it back on. It's stupid, but it will take less time than you spent writing this question.

Comment: ok, try `chmod 755 foldername`

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I'm actually more interested in learning what's going on than in solving the problem.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Done. Still not letting me `rmdir` or `rm -rf` it.

Comment: @JamesJensen Hmm, nothing interesting on the Preferences directory; how about on the parent Library directory? Actually, try `ls -laeO@ /opt/local/var/macports/home`. That'll list the home directory (as "."), macports (as ".."), and Library, and should show anything interesting about any of them. BTW, I also added the `-@` option, which'll show extended attributes (I don't think they're relevant, but just in case...).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Sorry for the late reply; I was away from my MacBook all weekend. I've posted the results of the command. I think that may have turned up something interesting.

Comment: @JamesJensen Hmm, I don't know of anything that FinderInfo would contain that could cause this, but just in case, try printing its contents with `xattr -l /opt/local/var/macports`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Done. Results added. (Thanks so much for this, btw, even if we don't find anything.)

Comment: @JamesJensen That's really weird; that com.apple.FinderInfo value *should* correspond to the "invisible" flag, which `ls -lO` *should* show as "hidden" (while it actually listed the flags as "-" i.e. none). But in any case, that shouldn't affect access into it.

Comment: One other thing occurs to me: is there an actual user account that .../macports/home is the home directory for? If so, it might be some weird effect of the new privacy protection feature in Mojave. Try granting the Terminal app access in Security & Privacy preferences -> Privacy tab -> Application Data (see [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/361707/how-macos-mojaves-privacy-protection-works/)), and then see if you can delete them.

Comment: @GordonDavisson That did it. I also looked up the users with `dscacheutil -q user` and found a user named "macports" with `/opt/local/var/macports/home` as its home directory. Bizarre. Thank you!

Comment: @GordonDavisson If you want to write that up an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 8):

The directory is SIP-protected because it is the home directory for a `macports` user, presumably created as part of the MacPorts installation process.

The best solution is to first remove that user account, following the instructions in [this accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320714/264486) to another AppleSE question. You may also wish to remove the corresponding `macports` group that also exists.

Specifically, the following commands will remove the user and group:

```
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "/Users/macports"
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "/Groups/macports"
```

The [MacPorts website uninstall page](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) mentions deleting the user and group but does not note that it is necessary due to SIP-protection to do this before deleting the folders. I think they also have an error in the syntax of their `dscl` command.

Once you have done that, you should be able to `sudo rm -rf /opt/local` successfully.

Significant credit for this answer is due to @GordonDavisson for providing 90% of the solution in comments, some months ago.

Comment: `delete: Invalid Path
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)`

Answer (score -1):

Try one of the following

o You are not the owner of the directory

ls -ld /path/to/directory

o You do not have permissions to remove the directory name from the parent directory

o The directory or it's parent has an ACL that is preventing you from deleting the directory

ls -ldeO@ /path/to/directory

ls -ldeO@ /path/to/directory/..

chmod to mess with ACLs

o The directory or its parent has 'uchg' or 'schg' flag

ls -ldeO@ /path/to/directory

ls -ldeO@ /path/to/directory/..

chflags to mess with flags.

**and finally this** `sudo chflags -R nouchg <parent>`

Comment: Op ran the command under sudo so does not matter who is the owner.