# Macports and Xcode

Tags: xcode, macports

help I have no idea what I'm doing. I wanted a photo editing software on my MacBook Pro running big sir. I came across gimp and it suggested I install it using macports. I ran the macports installer without knowing I was supposed to install Xcode first and now I don't know what that would have done to my computer since as far as I know I don't have Xcode. I want a do over. How do I find and remove whatever the macports installer would have put on my customer?

Answer (score 3):

You can uninstall MacPorts using their official instructions:
https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html

> ```
> sudo port -fp uninstall installed
> sudo dscl . -delete /Users/macports
> sudo dscl . -delete /Groups/macports
> sudo rm -rf \
>     /opt/local \
>     /Applications/DarwinPorts \
>     /Applications/MacPorts \
>     /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \
>     /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \
>     /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
>     /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
>     /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
>     /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
>     ~/.macports
> ```

Now MacPorts is removed, you can install Gimp without MacPorts using a regular installer from their website: from https://www.gimp.org/, choose Download, then Download Directly.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/how-to-delete-macports-user-after-using-the-migration-assistant#comment662324_320714