# Delete MacPorts group

Tags: homebrew, migration, macports, ventura

I tried all the solutions mentioned in the below links but the MacPorts group is still there:

```bash
➜  ~ dscacheutil -q group | grep "macports"
users: root myusernameeee macports _nsurlstoraged _serialnumberd
```

The only remaining thing from MacPorts is the group. there is no user as MacPorts anymore after running delete commands.

I have tried these:

- [How to delete MacPorts user after using the Migration Assistant](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/how-to-delete-macports-user-after-using-the-migration-assistant)
- https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html

---

- I tried to reinstall MacPorts and then uninstall it again but didn't help.
- I migrated from an Intel MacOS to a Silicon MacOS and MacPorts had created during that process; I had not installed MacPorts before migration.
- Both OSs before migration had the same OS version: Ventura 13.2.1
- During the migration process, when Migration Assistant said you could give a password to your own user or I create a temporary user, I set a password for my own user
- I didn't give admin privileges to the temporary user (there was a button in front of the temporary user to give that permission)
- As I had not installed MacPorts by myself before migration, there was on MacPorts application; so, `sudo port -fp uninstall installed` resulted `port: command not found`
- MacPorts user is not at the login screen and Settings->Users&Groups.
- Running `sudo ls /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users` results: `daemon.plist,myusernameeee.plist,nobody.plist,root.plist`

**Update:**

```bash
➜  ~ dscl . list /Users | grep -v '^_'
daemon
myusernameeee
nobody
prey
root
```

```bash
➜  ~ /usr/bin/dscl . -search /Users name macports
➜  ~
```

```bash
sudo ls /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users

...
_jabber.plist           _www.plist
_kadmin_admin.plist     _wwwproxy.plist
_kadmin_changepw.plist      _xserverdocs.plist
_knowledgegraphd.plist      daemon.plist
_krb_anonymous.plist        myusernameeee.plist
_krb_changepw.plist     nobody.plist
_krb_kadmin.plist       prey.plist
_krb_kerberos.plist     root.plist
_krb_krbtgt.plist
```

```bash
➜  ~ sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "/Groups/macports"
delete: Invalid Path
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)
```

```bash
➜  ~ dscacheutil -q group | grep "macports"
users: root myusernameeee macports _nsurlstoraged _serialnumberd
```

```bash
➜  ~ sudo find /Volumes/External -user macports
find: -user: macports: no such user
➜  ~ sudo find ~ -user macports
find: -user: macports: no such user
```

Comment: Doesn't the dscacheutil -q group show macports is a user not a group - which group is it a part of? I don't see that setup in my Ventura

Comment: I see your comments on https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320714/237 - try removing the user macports

Comment: `dscacheutil -q group` -> `name: staff password: * gid: 20 users: root myusernameeee macports _nsurlstoraged _serialnumberd`. Whether it is a group or a user, how to delete it? Cause I do not have it in login scree, or Settings User&Group either

Comment: Based on your comments, this indeed is a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/how-to-delete-macports-user-after-using-the-migration-assistant (all your dscacheutil output shows that there is a *user* `macports` belonging to group `staff`). Please follow the steps in the accepted answer there to remove the user.

Comment: If these steps fail, please copy/paste the whole part (all commands and their output) into the question and flag it for reopening (or mention me in the comments here).

Comment: @nohillside Done. I already mentioned that the link didn't answer my situation, but anyway, I updated the question and added each commands' results. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It helps to understand whether there was a misunderstanding/typo in the commands you run, or whether something more complex is at miss.